# distance in nonEuclidean geometries

Tags: projective-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Although I read some threads

[hermitian distance functions and geometry in complex space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97572/hermitian-distance-functions-and-geometry-in-complex-space)

[Geodesics and Distance in Hyperbolic Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218099/geodesics-and-distance-in-hyperbolic-space)

[Distances in geodesic triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601392/distances-in-geodesic-triangles)

https://www.jstor.org/stable/27958625?seq=1

They are FAR, FAR above my ability to understand. I have done trig, linear algebra in multiple dimensions,  calculus at the university level but never was exposed to differential geometry. I am basically a simpleton.

I cannot get a handle on how to calculate distance in a nonEuclidean Geometry. For example, we know that distance in euclidean space is calculated as the root of the sum of the squared distances in the x and y directions. Basically the hypoteneuse of a right triangle. In spherical space, with a vertex of the triangle at the pole and the opposite side at the equator, then the hypotenuse is equal to the vertical leg. I even figured out how to calculate distance on a paraboloid and ellipsoid, but these are simple geometric shapes.

How can I define a surface such that the the hypotenuse of a triangle is the sum of the length of the two legs?

This post

[Why don't we have many non euclidean geometries out there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615065/why-dont-we-have-many-non-euclidean-geometries-out-there)

seems to come close to what I am asking, but even it is at the limits of my grasp. Do I need to study differential geometry to figure this out? I viewed thi

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBY4G2o7DhF38OEvEImfR2heX7Szmq5Gs

but it seems somewhat abstract.

I do not even know what I need to know.